# Git deleting things mysteriously (edit: actually django-storages)

Tags: django, git, amazon-s3, git-branch, django-storage

The issue: sometimes, but not every time, Git deletes the `static` directory of a repo. We're not sure what triggers it, but it appears to happen when either merging between branches or sometimes even just checking out branches. It does this without asking, and eats tracked files.

The background:

- I have a (private) project which has a few branches, 'release', 'develop', multiple feature lines.
- There are two of us (me and @stevejalim) working on the repo. This problem happens to both of us.
- I am using purely the command line for my git commands; Steve is using a mixture of the command line and Git Tower.
- It's a Django project with a `static` directory. We may have `git rm`ed the `static` directory at some point in the past, or put it in `.gitignore`, but not recently. And the head of our develop branch doesn't have `static` in `.gitignore` and has files in `static` tracked.
- This happens so infrequently that we're not sure if it's something we're doing, or an intermittent problem, a bug with Git, or a corrupted tree
- It *might* happen only when merging another branch back into `develop`. But branches are *always* branched from `develop` and back into `develop`. But we're not sure.
- We are using git-flow, but the issue happens when using non-git-flow commands, too.
- As examples of when this can strike:

  1) Steve had a develop branch that was clean (no changes to commit or stage) and stable. He cut a new release with `git flow release start|finish` and in the process (possibly the back-merge from master to develop), the entire /static/ tree got deleted.

  2) Steve repaired the delete by discarding the changes (to essentially undelete the file). But then, Steve simply switched from master back to develop and the /static/ dir got zapped again (this was with Git Tower)

  3) Sometimes just merging from a feature branch to develop as an interim merge can trigger it. It does seem to happen most often when cutting a new release, though

Could it be related to how we repair the zapping of the /static/ dir? What is the best way to bulk-undelete things that have been deleted? Neither discarding local changes or a hard reset to HEAD seems to cure things. Might a rebase help us?

**UPDATE** We've just experienced this again simply with a `git add .` - no changing branches, no merging. Does that help diagnosis at all?

Here is the content of Steve's .git/config:

```
[core]
   repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:foobarbazbam/bar.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag = 
[difftool "tower"]
    cmd = \"/Applications/Tower.app/Contents/Resources/CompareScripts/kaleidoscope.sh\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Here is the content of `.gitignore`:

```
.DS_Store
*.pyc
*.log
*.log.*
*.bak
*~
settings_local.py
/build/
/static_collected/*
/static/uploads/*
/static/theme_files/*
/static/picture/*
pip-log.txt
*.tmproj
*.dot
*.db
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
/docs/_*
```

Comment: @sehe it was only a passing comment! I'll incorporate the extra info into the question. And sorry, this isn't a public repo.

Comment: @stevejalim @Joe - `ok` shame you can't link to a repo with the problem. I'd peruse `find .git/ -print0 | xargs -0 grep -w static` and `git log -- static/`, especially making sure the directory is never technically empty. Empty directories aren't tracked by git. Also, I'd consider sparse checkouts or submodules playing tricks on your minds.

Comment: By the way, you may be able to 'distill' the actual problm by doing `git filter-branch` to remove the things you don't want to expose. It would seriously help you get an answer if you could package it up in a tiny shared repo. (see http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html#removing_objects)

Comment: Thanks sehe - I'll take a look at both of the things you suggest later. I'm afraid there's no way we're making the current repo public, and I'm sceptical whether we could replicate it in a tiny shared repo - are you suggesting forking and massively deleting from the main repo, leaving just a few files?

Comment: If the directory gets deleted in one branch and not modified in another branch, it will be deleted during merge. Could that be the cause?

Comment: @knittl yes that's what I think may be happening. But, the feature branches always come off `develop` and are always integrated back. And the static directory is never deleted by us on purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay ladies and gents I have a public apology to make. **Git was not to blame**. I will leave this question here as a lesson to other people who may pass the same way.

We were using the django-storages backend (a 'plugin' to enable Django to store files on Amazon S3 transparently). This has a test called `HashPathStorageTest`. The tear-down this test deletes `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`, which was set to `./static`. This is faulty, in my opinion. It has no business blanket-deleting files that it didn't create.

We were running our tests, like good citizens, before checking in. Most of the time we ran only tests for our code, but occasionally we ran tests for the whole project (including 3rd party plugins). This was producing the behaviour in the question. Because we ran test  and git things together, it wasn't easy to pin down which command was doing the deleting (and the deleted files only showed up when we ran `git status`).

So problem solved. Again, sorry for casting aspersions on the good name of Git!

Comment: Did you file a bug report for django-storages?  You definitely should!

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be git deciding to merge to a branch which A) has the folder deleted B) it thinks is more recent than the branch you are merging to. Might there be a machine which has american date type and one which has european date type? Or does any of your testing involve resetting machine date time?

I would

a) check the regions of all machines included in your developement.
b) choose a fixed point in your development, copy the files out and create a new reprository and go from there.

Comment: Very interesting. We are only checking in on two machines, and they are both UK time. The time is never messed with. But perhaps the git log has become corrupted somehow, with a future date? We are considering re-basing (if that is the right word) the repository at some point if the issue becomes too much of a problem.

Comment: git doesn't care about either authorship date or commit dates when it comes to history, it only cares about commit parentage. Bad dates cannot cause git to perform merges in a different way.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - any suggestions then? I'm stumped. (FWIW there are no future dates in the log)

Comment: @Joe: Without access to your repository and a complete test case it's impossible to say.

Comment: Yeah sadly that might be it. No test case as it happens too intermittently to be able to come up with a hypothesis. Was hoping to perhaps get some verification advice.

Comment: git may not care about dates for history, but when it comes to (recursive) merge it has to know which is the most relevant version. you might try downloading a eval version of smart git - the log interface is quite pretty, and you can easily see the logs for individual files and the changes made - never looked at complete folders before though

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this just happened - I'm adding it a separate answer because its so silly. We have a repositiory for our SQL scripts and a new developer accidentally edited .gitignore to contain *.sql - needless to say changes stopped being propagated on that branch - and fortunately it was caught prior to any signifficant loss of development time. However its not inconcievable that this could produce the issues above - so have you checked your git directive files? If the folder is ignored (and .gitignore is in there as well - i.e ignored) it could dissapear and reappear almost by magic.